# How to use JpaMessageIdRepository in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm trying to get JpaMessageIdRepository to work in my Spring Boot 2.3 project but getting nowhere. It's the first argument in the function jpaMessageIdRepository that looks like this that puzzles me.

```
jpaMessageIdRepository(String persistenceUnit, String processorName) 
jpaMessageIdRepository(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, String processorName)
```

Which one should I use? And how to get the entityManagerFactory from within my class? Can't seem to find a working example anywhere :(

This is from my camel-route which doesn't work:

```
        .idempotentConsumer(
                header("CamelFileName"),
                jpaMessageIdRepository("what", "FileRepo")
        )
        .log("${header.CamelFileName}")
```

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to run it successfully with spring-boot 2.5.4, camel 3.13.0 and hibernate 5.4.32.Final. I'm not sure this is best way to do it but documentation is very poor on this topic.

There is no mention about creating sql tables here https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/jpa-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration
but found some useful information here on https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/sql-component.html

Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jpa-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Creating sql table and sequence

```
CREATE TABLE CAMEL_MESSAGEPROCESSED
(
    id             number(38) primary key not null,
    processor_name VARCHAR(255),
    message_id     VARCHAR(100),
    created_at     TIMESTAMP
);

create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 50;
```

Jpa entity configuration (spring bean) to include entity `org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jpa.MessageProcessed`

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@EntityScan(basePackages = {
        "project.base.package.to.do",
        "org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jpa"
})
@Configuration
class JpaEntityConfiguration {
}
```

Creating JpaMessageIdRepository. Processor name should be changed. EntityManagerFactory is autowired from spring context.

```
private JpaMessageIdRepository createJpaMessageIdRepository(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return JpaMessageIdRepository.jpaMessageIdRepository(entityManagerFactory, "helloSOProcessor");
}
```

Override id generation strategy (only if you use sequence with name than other hibernate_sequence and don't want to create hibernate_sequence). Create orm.xml under META-INF

```
<entity-mappings>
    <entity class="org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jpa.MessageProcessed" name="MessageProcessed">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="sequence" generator="sequenceGenerator"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: can you share GitHub link where you implemented this thing

Comment: @Zakirsaifi don't have any

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the EntityManagerFactory

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

And the use it:

```
.idempotentConsumer(
            header("CamelFileName"),
            jpaMessageIdRepository(emf, "FileRepo")
    )
    .log("${header.CamelFileName}")
```

Comment: I get this:  [host:2222/files/] o.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter : no persistent classes found for query class: select x from org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jpa.MessageProcessed x where x.processorName = ?1 and x.messageId = ?2
o.a.c.p.i.jpa.JpaMessageIdRepository Something went wrong trying to add message to repository {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ordinal parameter [1], expecting one of [] at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]

Comment: Looks like spring boot isn't auto creating the tables :(